# Unable to read session variable when I am calling it from Ajax but I can read if I call it from controller in ASP.Net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have created a method inside controller and trying to read session variable value from it and I am calling this method from Ajax jQuery but I am not able to get the value.
There is another method where I am trying to read session value and calling it from controller itself then I can read.
I have not worked much on sessions in  MVC .Net. Please see my code-

```
           $("#Value").on('click', function () {
                    $("#Modal").modal("hide");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "Home/GetData",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { flag: 1, Id: '@employeeId' },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == 'True') {

                                console.log("Data Saved")
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

and GetData method is written in HomeContoller and I am assigning Key in Index method of Homecontoller.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetData(int Flag, string EmployeeId)
{
string Token= string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Key"]) ? string.Empty : (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Key"];
}
```

Comment: Not getting your question exactly, can you please add the code for more clarity.

Comment: Share the relevant code

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have added coded- request you to please see and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you can read it easily since *Session is **server side** object. You can not access it directly in jQuery. You can write an HttpHandler that will share the session*

---

Below is another way to do like in your View (.cshtml):

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSession" data-value="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["keyName"]" />
```

---

script is something like below to read the session value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = '@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["keyName"]';
});
```